# JSON param through Guzzle 6 post always errors out

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

It always errors out saying one of 2 messages. 
`{"message":"Required field 'specList' is not specified"}` or if I add `specList` then it says `'400 Bad Request' response: {"message":"Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token"}`

This is what I have:

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://someURL/PrismGateway/services/rest/v1/']);
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'vms/'.$vmId.'/clone',
        [
            'verify' => false,
            'auth' => ['user', 'pass'],
            'json' => [
                'specList' => '[{"name":"test9"}]'
                //tried 'create.dto.acropolis.VMCloneDTO' => '{"specList":[{"name":"test9"}]}'
            ]
        ]
    );
```

If I use `create.dto.acropolis.VMCloneDTO` it tells `{"message":"Required field 'specList' is not specified"}` and if I change it up to `specList` it gives me the deserialize error from above. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the actual param in the api is listed as `create.dto.acropolis.VMCreateDTO` and it expects the `specList` response as a json data type.

Someone help me figure out why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Got rid of the `json` and added `body`:

```
'body' => '{"specList":[{"name":"test9"}]}'
```